# Deadlock при обработке подписчика redis

Tags: php, websocket, redis

Делаю соккет сервер для передачи данных использую редис пабсаб. При подписке на канал все хорошо, сообщения получаю. Если пытаться как то нагружать сервер, например постоянными реконнектами, то получаю дедлок на чтение сообщения из канала. Использую swoole